# If there exists $n$ independent vectors $y_{i}\in \mathbb{R}^{n}, f'(x;y_{i})=0, \forall x \in B(a,r)$. Prove that $f$ is a constant in $B(a,r)$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function in an open ball $B(a,r)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. If there exists $n$ independent vectors $y_{1},y_{2},...,y_{n}$ such that $f'(x;y)=0$, for all $x \in B(a,r)$. Prove that $f$ is a constant function in $B(a,r)$.
How can I prove it? I was thinking about that if $f'(x;y)=0$ in $B(a,r)$, so $f$ is constant function in $B(a,r)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n$ indepedent vectors span $\mathbb R^{n}$. Hence any linear map  $\mathbb R^{n} \to \mathbb R$ which vanishes at $n$ independent vectors vanishes identically. Hence $f'(x)=0$ for all $x$. Can you now show that $f$ is a constant?

Comment: How $\beta=\{y_{1},y_{2},...,y_{n}\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then the hypothesis of my problem becomes $f'(x;y)=0$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and for all vector $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Comment: $\mathbb R^{n}$ is an $n-$ dimensional vector space. Hence any $n$ linearly independent vectors form a basis. @Ramanujan

Comment: Ok, I understand that. Then the problem is equivalent to: "Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an open and connected set. If $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ has all the directional derivatives at every point $x \in U$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(x)=0$ for all $v$. Prove $f$ is a constant function."?

Comment: Yes and you can use the one-dimensional result to complete the proof. Take any two points $a$ and $b$, join them by  a line segment. You will get a differentiable function with derivative $0$ on this  segment. This implies $f(a)=f(b)$.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I can to prove it. Thanks @Kavi Rama Murthy